# I'm making a Java interactive novel, but my JTextArea Disappears

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, adventure

My adventure game has a bunch of nested if statements to output something based on the input, but my JTextField only gets one input and then disappears. I want to get the JTextField to take unlimited inputs and use .append to to show them in the jtextarea.  I want to have the program continue to take user inputs until the story path in the if statements end. If want to get input from a JTextField and put the output in the JTextArea and keep it there.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Reader; 

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

    /*JakeBarcelona
    *Date:May 5, 2016
    *Program Name:StoryTester.java
    *Description: 
    */



public class StoryTester extends JFrame
{
    static JTextField input = new JTextField(30);
    static JTextArea fields = new JTextArea(30,50);
    static Story ARoom=new Story();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        String story=new String();
        JLabel intro = new JLabel(story); 
        //Sets the JLabels font and color


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//puts a red x to close it
        Story wow = new Story();
        String introduction=wow.intro();
        //creates array field for text editing
        fields.insert(introduction, 0);

        String name= fields.getText(0,30);




        //creates new Panel
        JPanel myPanel=new JPanel();


        //creates label for text box
        myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
        myPanel.add(fields);
        myPanel.add(input);

        //puts a scroll bar and cancel and ok button
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(fields, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        myPanel.add(scroll);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, "Story", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        {

         String jake = input.getText();

         String need = ARoom.storyStatements(jake);
         System.out.println(need);
         fields.append(need);

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. I'm looking at your code a second time and I see that myPanel has been added to a JOptionPane. Is it supposed to be displayed in the JOptionPane or is it supposed to be displayed in the main JFrame GUI?

Comment: It's supposed to be displayed in the JOptionPane, I get input from the JTextField, and display the text in the JTextArea

Comment: Please edit your question and spell out clearly as possible exactly what you're trying to do. What the myPanel is supposed to do, whether it's supposed to remain in view and be the main GUI, how it relates to the JFrame, anything that will help us to better understand your program and your problem.

Comment: Updated my question. In essence I want the JTextArea and field to stay their as the user keeps inputing answers. I want the JTextField to keep getting the users input and the JTextArea to keep displaying the output.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding fields twice to the GUI, once to myPanel and once to the JScdrollPane, scrool, which is then added to myPanel. Don't do this, but rather add it to the JScrollPane only. You're also artificially constraining the size of your myPanel JPanel, and this is likely what's getting you into trouble.

Instead use layouts in a smart way by for instance giving myPanel a BorderLayout, adding the JScrollPane to the BorderLayout.CENTER position and the inputs JTextField to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END position. And don't set the preferred size of myPanel but rather let the text component column and row properties set their preferred size which will in turn set the preferred size of the myPanel JPanel.

Also you're using static fields inappropriately and in fact none of your current fields should be static.

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutEg extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 50;
    private static final int ROWS = 30;
    private JTextField input = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextArea fields = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);

    public LayoutEg() {
        // two methods below so that words wrap
        fields.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        fields.setLineWrap(true);
        fields.setFocusable(false); // so we can't write directly into JTextArea
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fields);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LayoutEg mainPanel = new LayoutEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Story GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I get errors everytime I change them from static also I'm using java 1.6.

Comment: @JakeBarcelona: the version of Java doesn't matter for this, (although it does matter for what I do in the main method). If you are getting errors, then you're fixing the errors backwards. The solution is not to make the fields static but to not access them in a static way. In fact they should all be private instance fields, and you should mutate or access them only through controlled public methods. This is basic Java and is something you should be learning before jumping into GUI coding.